# Check validates_presence_of for variable set of attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a object Product, with a category and some other attributes.
Different attributes are required in different categories. Every attribute as an array of required_attributes.
How should i implement this?
I tried something like this:

```
validates_presence_of lambda { *self.category.required_properties }
```

I also tryed this:

```
def validate(record)
    if record.category == nil
       record.errors[:category] << "Has no Category"
    else
       recors.category.required_properties.each do |x|
        .........?????  
       end
    end
end
```

What would be the cleanest way of doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a conditional validation for each attribute that checks if it is included in the list for the current category:

```
[:attribute1, :attribute2, :attribute3].each do |attribute|
  validates attribute, :presence => true,
    :if => Proc.new { |product| product.category.required_properties.include?(attribute) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
validates :name, :presence => true
```

or

```
validates :name, :presence => {:message => 'Name cannot be blank, Task not saved'}
```

We can check using **if record.category.present?**

```
def validate(record)
  if record.category.present?
      record.category.required_properties.each do |x|
       .........?????  
      end
  else
      record.errors[:category] << "Has no Category"
  end
end
```

Comment: and for the ".....????" could i do something like "validate_presents_of x" x is a symbol?

Comment: Yes, you can check **if x.present?** or **if x.some_property.present?** .... like wise